# Why does tensorflow say a Tensor is not an element of this graph when training an Estimator many times?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

Consider the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.estimator.model_fn import EstimatorSpec
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.layers import Dense


def model_fn_1(features, labels, mode):
    x = [[1]]
    labels = [[10]]
    m = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]], tf.float32)
    lookup = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(m, x, name='embedding_lookup')

    preds = Dense(1)(lookup)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(labels - preds)
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss, tf.train.get_global_step())

    eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, preds)}
    return EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


model_1 = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn_1)
model_1.train(input_fn=lambda: None, steps=1)
```

As expected, I can execute `model_1.train(input_fn=lambda: None, steps=1)` multiple times and the training will continue from the previous execution.

Now, consider the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.estimator.model_fn import EstimatorSpec
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.layers import Embedding, Dense

def model_fn_2(features, labels, mode):
    x = tf.constant([[1]])
    labels = [[10]]
    m = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
    m = Embedding(2, 2, weights=[m], input_length=1, name='embedding_lookup')
    lookup = m(x)

    preds = Dense(1)(lookup)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(labels - preds)
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss, tf.train.get_global_step())

    eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, preds)}
    return EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


model_2 = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn_2)
model_2.train(input_fn=lambda: None, steps=1)
```

In this case, I can execute `model_2.train(input_fn=lambda: None, steps=1)` only once and when i attempt to execute it again, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot
>   be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor
>   Tensor("embedding_lookup/embeddings:0", shape=(2, 2),
>   dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may a bug or an unsupported case in tensorflow keras backend: session is cached globally and is not cleared. You can clear it manually by calling:

```py
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.backend import clear_session
clear_session()
```

... between `train` invocations.

Short reason: the second `train` call builds a new graph with new nodes, however the under-the-hood session holds the previous graph, which makes them incompatible.

**Update**. In the latest tensorflow, keras has been moved to another package, now it looks even simpler:

```py
from keras.backend import clear_session
clear_session()
```

Comment: If the under the hood session always holds the previous graph, why don't I need to clear the session for the code in the first snippet?

Comment: In my case, the import failed (not sure if it's due to a TF update or what). Using directly `from keras.backend import clear_session` worked though.

Comment: @Overdrivr thanks, it's been moved out of `contrib` then, thanks. I'll update the answer